# How to use table of indices to solve a congruence?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

I have trouble understanding the link between completing a table of indices to the base 3 modulo 17 (for example - which I can do just fine) and being asked to use the table to solve a congruence like $ 7^x \equiv 6 (mod 17)$

What am I not getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: After computing the table, you should be able to find $a$ and $b$ such that 
$$3^a\equiv 7\mod 17\quad\text{and}\quad 3^b\equiv6\mod17.$$

Now, write $7^x\equiv6\mod17$ as $$3^{ax}\equiv3^b\mod17.$$